# Some users say that they are unable to see discount on website, but when we check from our end it is visible in magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

When some users place an order on our website, they do not see the discount price; the original price shows when we place the order ourselves.
There is no issue for testing, we have checked in a lot of pc and mobile, I have flushed the command of Reindex and also flush cache.only facing issue by customer please suggest me .

magento 2.1.1

Comment: Is cron setup properly? Also, you are giving discount from catalog price rule I guess?

Comment: yes but when we test or buy product getting no issue of discount price when customer buy the product he give complaint discount price not showing.

Comment: Have you checked your server timezone? Server timezone should match magento 2 timezone, otherwise there may be a time lag for running cron which may cause this issue.Please check.